# Trying to sum values of two arrays

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to sum the values of an "arrayA" with values of another "arrayB" and assign this sum in the same position where the index is in "arrayA", but the output is a result that I do not understand. Please, could someone help me?

Code:

```
.data
        arrayA: .word 1,12,35,473,2,32,4
        arrayB: .word 0,3,12,32,3,4,9
        length: .word 7
        count: .word 0
        line: .asciiz "\n"
        sum: .word 0
  .text
    MAIN:
        la $s1, arrayA 
        la $s2, arrayB 
        lw $t3, length
        li $t4, 0
        lw $t5, count
FOR: 
        beq $t3, $t4, EXIT
        lw $t0, ($s1)
        lw $t1, ($s2)
        add $t0, $t0, $t1
        sw $t0, ($s1)
        sw $t0, sum
        li $v0, 1
        la $a0, sum
        syscall
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, line
        syscall
        addi $t4, $t4, 1
        addi $s1, $s1, 4
        addi $s2, $s2, 4
        j FOR
EXIT:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Output:

```
268501060
268501060
268501060
268501060
268501060
268501060
268501060
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a0` is a different name for `$4`. So you're trying to use the same register for more than one thing at the same time (the address of the current element in `arrayA`, and the argument for a couple of system calls), which obviously doesn't work.

I'd suggest that you use a different register to hold the address of `arrayA`. And also to use the conventional register names (`$v0`, `$a1`, `$t2`, etc) at all times to avoid mistakes like these.

---

You're also using system call 1 incorrectly:

```
la $a0, sum
```

System call 1 expects the value to print to be placed in `$a0`, but you're placing the address of the value in `$a0`. Instead of `la` you should be using `lw` here. Of course, the `sum` variable is unncessary since you could've just added `$t0` and `$t1` into `$a0` directly.

Comment: Michael, I changed the register name of "arrayA" as "arrayB", but the problem persists. I changed the code of my question.

Comment: The way you're printing the sum is incorrect. See my updated answer. And please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, now the code is working. I'm studying MIPS and it's a little hard because I haven't experience. Thanks again, you´re the best.